# Hide app icons in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, hide

I had a concept for a project that I wanted to verify was actually possible in iOS 10. I want to create an application that can populate a list of apps currently installed. The user should be able to select certain applications from that list that they want to hide the icon for so that the application cannot be accessed. Is it possible to hide certain applications without jailbreaking the iPhone? I looked around and found a partial solution to hide apps in older versions of iOS by adding this to the Info.plist to hide the app in the SpringBoard:

```
    <key>SBAppTags</key>
    <array>
      <string>hidden</string>
    </array>
```

This made it seem like only the current application could not be displayed, but that may just be my misunderstanding. Can the Info.plist be changed while an application is running to hide other applications? Making them not accessible would work as a possible solution. Maybe adding a passcode to the applications? This is solution wouldn't have to go through the Apple Store or anything.

Thoughts/comments are appreciated!

Comment: Not programmatically, but if you want to lock down what apps are available you could look at using Apple configurator.

Answer (score 0):

There already exists an app ([OurPact](http://ourpact.com/)) that does this for parental control. They seem to be making some creative use of Apple's [Mobile Device Management](https://www.apple.com/support/education/mdm/)

So, to answer the question: It seems to be possible.

Comment: That's a good solution for something similar to what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to do everything in a single application though without having to use another device.

Comment: Then the answer is "no, you can't"